# Users Cannot Open Document In folder to edit

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, excel

I have a Site with a Document Library with a User with Full Control. We are running in https mode.

The users cannot open the Spread Sheet for editing, though I can. The site is also asking her to log in before she opens it (it opens in read-only).

This is happening across the site.

Comment: Did you modified `web.config` file by any chance?

Comment: with one user or all user with full control? what are your permission?